# is it possible to write a single perl cgi script to serve all http requests

Tags: perl, cgi

I am wondering if it is possible to use a single perl cgi script to server all http requests to my site, no matter what relative URL given by the visitors.

Please share your thoughts. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per request of the submitter, I'm submitting a more-complete version of the HTTPD script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Daemon;
my $PORT = 89;
my $server = HTTP::Daemon->new(LocalPort =>$PORT);

# Init
print "Starting server at $server->url\n";
print "You can also use http://localhost:$PORT if browsing from the same machine running this script.\n\n";

# Server
my $count=0;
while (my $client = $server->accept) {
  CONNECTION:
    while (my $request = $client->get_request) {
    $count++;
    print "Connection #$count:\n";
        print $request->as_string;
    print "\n";
        $client->autoflush;
      RESPONSE:
    print $client "Relative URL used was " . $request->url->path;
    last CONNECTION;
    }
    $client->close;
    undef $client;
}
```

Instead of the simple line that prints "Relative URL used was", you'd most likely want to parse the URL used to perform whatever different functions you need this script to do for every HTTP request.

Answer (score 4):

If you call your script `index.cgi` and combine that with a `mod_rewrite` rule to redirect all requests to `/index.cgi/foo` then `foo` will be available as `$ENV{'PATH_INFO'}`, thereby letting you know what the original request path was.

Comment: `index.cgi` can be made "invisible" by mapping it to the root `/` with [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex). `mod_rewrite` gyrations are absolutely not necessary.

Comment: mod_rewrite is an Apache directive. If you are using a different web server, other directives will be needed.

Comment: @daxim I believe you're wrong - on my Apache installation asking for .../foo throws a 404 instead of retrieving .../index.cgi/foo

Comment: Alnitak, use [ScriptAlias**Match**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptaliasmatch), not ScriptAlias.

Comment: my test wasn't using ScriptAlias, just ExecCGI permissions on a directory containing an index.cgi file.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible using mod_rewrite as other people have said. But you probably don't want to do it in a CGI program. Far better to write a proper web application using something like [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) or [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) (probably with [Plack](http://plackperl.org/) at the back end).

Answer (score 3):

If you're not really committed to your existing web server, you could use something like this:

```
use HTTP::Daemon;  # need LWP-5.32 or better
use HTTP::Status; 
use HTTP::Response;
use URI::Heuristic;
my $server = HTTP::Daemon->new(LocalPort => 89);
my $this_url = $server->url;
```

etc.

I grabbed that snippet from an existing program that ran as its own web server.  Not sure how many of the "use" commands are required after the first one, but hopefully that gives you some ideas.

Comment: +1. I am very interested in knowing the details of this. Can you explain a bit or point me to some links? Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you mind giving a full working code here? Sorry that I am still unable to make it fully working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Qiang - see my newer post that has a complete functional script.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set up perl itself to do this. However, you should be able to configure your webserver to redirect all requests to a single CGI script, usually then passing the full script as a parameter. If you're running on Apache, look at `mod-rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't vote up neither comment to davorg by low reputation (I'm new here).

You can use Mojolicious framework too. Mojolicious::Lite allows you to write full apps in a single file (logic, templating, etc), and I guess you're searching for something like:

[http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojolicious::Lite#Wildcard_Placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojolicious%3a%3aLite#Wildcard_Placeholders)

More info at:

http://mojolicio.us/